# How to display only rendered rows and hide other in ui:repeat

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I need to display only selected rows in `<ui:repeat>` from search result. Here's my code:

```
<h:inputText value="#{user.lname}" required="false" class="defaultText1 c_8" title="Search   by user"></h:inputText>
<h:commandButton id="submit" name="submit"  action="#{user.retrieveMembersByName}" />

<ui:repeat id="dtable" var="u" value="#{user.getUserList()}" varStatus="status" rendered="#{not empty user.dataList}">

        <li>
        <a href="#">#{u.memberId}</a>
         <a href="#" >#{u.groupId}</a>
        <a href="#">#{u.fname}</a>
        <a href="#">#{u.mname}</a>
                </li>
</ui:repeat>
```

Right now it's displaying all rows. If I put `<ui:repeat value="#{user.dataList}">`, it will show me only searched single row. However, I want to show all rows and only if I search then it should show single row. Or can I make the searched row highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

Check for some condition and display an element with additional class to 'highlight' the result. If you want, change the other elements' class as well, i.e. to hide them.

The view:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{userBean.userName}" required="true" />
    <h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{userBean.search}" />
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty userBean.userList}">
        <ul>
            <ui:repeat value="#{userBean.userList}" var="user">
                <li class="#{fn:contains(user.name, userBean.userName) ? 'highlight' : 'grayed'}"><a href="#">#{user.name}</a></li>
            </ui:repeat>
        </ul>
    </ui:fragment>
</h:form>
```

This can be done with EL 2.2 method call with parameters as well, instead of using a [JSTL function](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html).

The bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

    private List<User> userList;//getter
    private String userName;//getter+setter
    public String search() {
        //load data and handle exceptions, if needed, do business job
        userList = userDAO.find(userName);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @skuntsel  thanks for the reply.....the highlight of rows works...but i want to hide the other rows when serched element was displayed.But its displaying all rows now.I have tried to check it with if() condition in Bean but noluck...can you let me how to do that.